# C++, an attribute of an object disappears when inserting/removing from a Heap

Tags: c++, oop, heap

Hello sorry if there are any problems in this post, it's my first time using the site and I'm a little desperate.

This is for school. The teacher provided us with a ready to use the code for a `Heap` class and a `Set` class and some other stuff. Out of the classes I made myself, there's one that has 4 attributes: 3 of them are `long double`s and one is a `std::vector` of `Set`s (not `std::set`s, teacher provided `Set`s).

I'm having a problem when inserting or removing objects of this class from the provided Heap. The objects inserted into the heap, when removed, are missing everything I've put on the `std::vector`.

A part from my `main` where it happens (save for debugging stuff)

```
PartialSolution temp; //this is the object
temp.includeSet(*s);
temp.Print(); //so far everything works fine
H.insert(temp);
PartialSolution l; 
l = H.top(); //written by teacher, gets first element from heap
l.Print(); //here the contents I've added with includeSet are gone
```

I'm pretty sure the problem can't be in the Heap since the teacher made it and also it uses a template clthe attributes of the objects on the objects attributes, but I really have no idea at all where the problem could be.

The vector is declared as

```
std::vector<Set> sets;
```

EDIT:
Solved, thanks. (Sorry if I'm doing it wrong, I'm not sure how else to close the question). The problem was in a `=` operator method for `PartialSolution` created by the teacher, that only copied the `long double` attributes and was used in the `Heap`. Added a line to copy the `std::vector` and it works fine now.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and [format](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks/) the code.

Comment: Probably [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing).

Comment: When you copy objects into and out of a collection then you have to observe the "c++ rule of three".  The quoted phrase is easy to google.